# Powershell: change view type of file system folder object

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, I created a new file system folder object:

```
New-Item -Path "c:\users\UserName" -Name "NewSubdirectoryName" -ItemType "directory"
```

If a user open this folder in the File Explorer, he will get a default view. I want to initialize this to something else with my Powershell script. It should be 'mid sized icons'. **How can I do that?**

Comment: What did you search for? What did you try? What happened?  SO does have rules. [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: New-Item has no method for manipulating the Windows Explore folder/file views. It only is for creation. You have to write code specifically for Explorer after selecting that specific folder, for that use case. If a user has set their explorer view at their root and set that to propagate, it will ignore anything you set. Why is your use case for doing this? If a user likes a specific view, for all their folders, and you change that without notice/consent, then you'd have very unhappy users.

Comment: @postanote I know and abide the SO rules. My question indeed does contain a workable MRE. I create a directory c:\users\UserName\NewSubdirectoryName for the user UserName. I search for a way to automatically set the view type of this directory after creation. What is not clear in the question?

Comment: @postanote And yes, I realize that there is no option for new-item to set the view type and that I have to do it programmically. Hence, that's what my question is about. The 'why' is not really important, is it? In this case, the users asked me to do it this way.

Comment: If your users asked for it, then that is a different matter, but that was not stated in your original post. All this kind of stuff is just registry settings. So, fire up the MS SysINternals tools, fileom.regmon/procexp, change the folder settigns manually and check what those tools tell you. Once you get the settings, then is just registry calls. Messing with teh registry via PowerShell is a well documented thing and built-in cmdlets to do that.

Comment: @postanote Regmon/Filemon have been discontinued in 2009 and procexp doesn't do the job, but procmon would.I have tried to find something with it, but couldn't pinpoint what call does the job. And I have been evaluating the registry. These settings are on a per user basis so I would expect them in HKCU. And they are on a per directory basis, so I would have hoped to find the name of the directory as a key value. I have also search the registry without success. About online docu regarding this problem: I have researched w/o success and found only similar open question. So perhaps you know?